# Name of plant with small red flowers

Tags: identification

What is the name of this low border plant with small deep red flowers?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to say for sure, the picture does not magnify well so it's not possible to see detail of the flowers or the leaves. Could be a Dianthus https://www.americanmeadows.com/perennials/dianthus/dianthus-fire-star or a Phlox subulata variety https://nova.co.at/marsNova/en/instance/picture/Phlox-subulata-Red-Wings.xhtml?oid=9255785. Could even be a Helianthemum, something like 'Red Dragon' or 'Sun Rose'. Need a better photo for accurate ID, but I'm guessing this image is from a book or a magazine or similar, rather than your own photo.

Comment: Given bloom time concurrent with Papaver and the location not in a rock garden, I'd be willing to bet it's a dianthus. Maybe a cultivar of Dianthus deltoides?

Comment: Thank you very much both for your very informative feedback. It is my photo but I was not able to upload the original (too big). I think it is a phlox subulata - red wing. But will certainly look into Dianthus now as they look gorgeous too.

Comment: @Jurp - depends where you live and how variable the climate is - Phlox subulata (one of the newer varieties)  is out now, along with Papaver just about to open up here in the south of the UK.

Comment: @Bamboo. Interesting point. My Phlox subulata (and a couple minor phlox species) have been done for three weeks and the poppies are beginning to bloom now. DIanthus (and I have many varieties) are in full bloom here. Woiuld be nice to know where the photo was taken.

Comment: @Fiona - If you like a red P. subulta, you might want to consider Phlox douglasii 'Oxblood'/'Oxenblut' (I've also seen it as 'Crackerjack', which is a different color). In my opinion, it's a better red than 'Red Wings', which has always looked magenta-y to me. Here's a link to a British nursery: https://slacktopnurseries.co.uk/index.php/plants/category/p The foliage is a little different than P. subulata, but the habit is the same.